# Can someone explain the logic behind this step in a induction problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

There is a question in the book that I don't quite understand.

> **Question**
>   Show that $n^2$ is smaller than $2^n$ whenever $n\ge5$.

At the $k+1$ step it gets very whacked and confusing.

> **$k+1$ step**
>   $$2^{k+1} = 2 \cdot 2^k > k^2 + k^2 > \mathbf{k^2 + 4k > k^2+2k+1}$$

Can someone explain to me where the book magically pulled out $4n$ because it seems to me that they replaced one of the $k^2$ by $4k$, but I have no idea why they did it and where that number $4k$ came from.

Comment: I suggest checking out [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) link to make your post more readable.

Comment: Also, you're sure they just introduced $n$ out of nowhere here?

Comment: well, we want to proce it for when n is greater or equal to 5

Comment: If it's not a misreading, it's a typo, and should be $$k^2 + k^2 > k^2 + 4k > k^2+2k+1.$$ Since by assumption, $k > 4$, we have $k^2 > 4k$.

Comment: im still not seeing where the 4k came from, sorry.

Comment: @Joe Well, look at it the other way around: $2k+1 < 2k+k = 3k < 4k < k^2$

Comment: If $k\geq 5$ by assumption, then it's also true that $k>4$. Since $k$ is positive, we can multiply both sides and conclude that $k^2>4k$.

Comment: What is the logic behind doing that though, how do we know we have to switch k^2 for 4k

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the $4n$-step, you only have to see that
$$k^2 > 2k+1 \qquad\forall\ k>5$$
This is rather simple to see since $2k+1 < 3k < k\cdot k = k^2$
It occurs to me that that $4n$ was supposed to say $4k$ wich is fine and works just as well as the $3k$-term does in my alternative.

Comment: How did 3k turn to k x k? I guess i am cobfused with what the steps are doing since i have never.done an equality induction problem..

Comment: Well we have $3<5<k$. Now multiply both sides by $k$.